# AFNetworking 2 how do I set a header that updates on each request

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am trying to figure out a way to update a authentication token that gets generated for each requests sent to my api.

I am currently subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager`

.h

```
@interface ZXHTTPSessionManager : ZXHTTPSessionManager

+ (ZXHTTPSessionManager *)sharedClient;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ZXHTTPSessionManager.h"

@implementation ZXHTTPSessionManager


+ (ZXHTTPSessionManager *)sharedClient
{
    static ZXHTTPSessionManager *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:APIBASEURL];

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"User-Agent": @"MY APP"}];

        _sharedClient = [[ZXHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL sessionConfiguration:config];
        _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (void)setAuthToken:(NSString *)token
{
    [[self requestSerializer] setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];
}

@end
```

Creating a task

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[ZXHTTPSessionManager sharedClient] GET:@"/post"
                            parameters:@{ @"id" : @"123"}
                               success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

                               } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

                               }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tiltem

Thanks, you helped me solve the answer to my question.

I dug more into the documentation, and read:

```
To change the behavior of all data task operation construction, which is also used in the GET / POST / et al. convenience methods, override dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:


- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    // Do custom
    return [super dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Comment: How do you catch each response ? Do you subclass a response serializer or are you doing something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently using AFHTTPSessionManager but I am sure it is somewhat similar. In AFHTTPClient each individual request is made in following method:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                  path:(NSString *)path
                            parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

You could modify it here. Or perhaps better approach is using the following method that is passed the NSMutableURLRequest returned from above method

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                                                success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

You can override this in your subclass and make changes needed to the urlRequest header. Note that this method takes a NSURLRequest so would need to create a mutable version of request.

do call to super after making mods to the header.

Answer (score 0):

if you use AFNetworking 2.0, you can overwrite HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest this method such as

```
#pragma mark - AFHTTPRequestOperationManager overridden methods
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation*)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
                                               success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject))success
                                               failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error))failure;
{
    //Add cookie into request headers.
    NSMutableURLRequest* modifiedRequest = request.mutableCopy;
    NSMutableDictionary* modifiedHeaders = [request.allHTTPHeaderFields mutableCopy];


    [modifiedHeaders setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36 abuMoviesDemo/1.0" forKey:@"User-Agent"];
    modifiedRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = modifiedHeaders;

    return [super HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:modifiedRequest success:success failure:failure];
}
```

If you use AFNetworking 3.0, it becomes simple to set requestSerializer of AFHTTPSessionManager. such as:

```
- (void)modifyUserAgent
{
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36 abuMoviesDemo/1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
}
```